# Не запускается код Java

Tags: java

Доброе утро, товарищи программисты!

Есть следующий код:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    class Party {
     public void buildInvite(){
      Frame f = new Frame();
      Label l = new Label("Вечеринка у Тима");
      Button b = new Button("Ваша ставка");
      Button c = new Button("Сбросить");
      Panel p = new Panel();
      p.add(l);
      }
   }
```

Программа компилируется, но не запускается в cmd, пишет отсутствует class

Comment: А причем тут `cmd` и `GUI` приложение?

Comment: Конкретно этот код не компилируется (я его подправил).

Comment: Какой класс отсутствует-то? Впрочем, неважно. В каждом java-приложении должен быть метод ``main()``. Это именно то, что запускается. В этом коде такой метод отсутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA),

> В каждом java-приложении должен быть метод `main()`

Или добавьте отдельный класс:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   Party party = new Party();
   party.buildInvite();
  }
}
```

Или добавьте в класс `Party` `main()`:

```
psvm {
 buildInvite();
}
```

`psvm` - стандартный заголовок `main` метода в `java`.

(`public static void main(String args[])`)

Или переименуйте `buildInvite` в `psvm`.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас нет класса в котором хранится метод  public static void main(String[]args). Соответственно и скомпилироваться ничего не может.
И что вы хотите увидеть в cmd?

Comment: "Программа компилируется"  --> "Соответственно и скомпилироваться ничего не может". Извините, а вы прочли вопрос полностъю?